# No Gap between images(logos) despite given cellspacing

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I wanted to put logos in a table in order to achieve a responsive design.
I am facing a problem while doing this here's my code:-

```
<table border="0"align="center" cellspacing="200px">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\lt.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\ncc.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
                <!-- considering it is on the same folder that .html file -->
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\asia engineering.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\lt.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\ncc.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\asia engineering.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\lt.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\ncc.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
                <!-- considering it is on the same folder that .html file -->
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\asia engineering.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\lt.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\ncc.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
                <!-- considering it is on the same folder that .html file -->
        <td><img src="C:\Users\varun\OneDrive\Desktop\conbusi\website\img\clients\asia engineering.png" alt="" border=0 height=100 width=100></img></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I run the code I found out that the logos were close together On the laptop you can see in the image given below:-

[The images are close together when I specified cell spacing = "200px"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibmak.png)

Comment: Hey welcome in the world of web front end development. Seeing you trying to do a layout with a table, I wanted to recommend that you abandon this idea, which has been depreciated for many years now, and turn to a more advanced technology such as [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp).

Comment: Thank you for helping me @johannchopin. I will try flexbox.